# iOS Swift UIImagePickerController Show Only Videos Whose Duration is Below a Specific Length

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uiimagepickercontrollermediatype

When presenting the `UIImagePickerController` to show mediaType `kUTTypeMovie`, how can I filter it so that it only shows videos that are under a specific duration?

Comment: You have make your own custom picker!

Comment: Is that pretty involved? Any links?

Comment: Search on google, shorthand use GitHub open source and add your logic

Answer (score 0):

You can filter video only using:

```
videoPicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
```

But filtering video under specific duration is not possible.